# Get the next/previous item in the array sorted by custom frontmatter only if it matches the todays date

Tags: collections, jekyll, liquid

UPDATED:
I have a collection called Events. Each item in this collection has a custom meta "Start time and date:" thats input as a date time format(e.g. 2017-02-23 00:05:09 +0700). In my home layout I list only events where "Start time and date:" matches todays date.

```
{% assign events = site.events | sort: 'Start time and date' %}
{% for event in events %}
  {% assign today = site.time | date: "%b %d" %}
  {% assign eventdate = event['Start time and date'] | date: "%b %d" %}
  {% if eventdate == today %}
   ...
  {% else %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Which results in a list of events that match todays date but the order of those on the system(not in the rendered list on home screen) is sorted by the default page.date and not event['Start time and date'].when I am located within event page and call for page.next i get not the next event in my generated list of todays events but the page.next which is the next event page in order which all of the events were created(I assume they are sorted by date).

How can I access next and previous event relative to the current event using my custom meta event['Start time and date'] and not the default event.date. Basicly get net or previous event with todays date.

Please help , i've exhausted my jekyll knowledge with this one.

Comment: I don't think you can have spaces in meta values. That will give you a liquid syntax error on using it.

Comment: You can just need to call it as {{post['meta name with spaces']}}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long struggle i was able to resolve this way, there is probably an easier and cleaner way to do this so i would be grateful if someone can do an edit of this to tidy it up =)

```
{% assign today = site.time | date: "%d" %} // find current date
{% assign allevents = site.events | sort: 'Start time and date' %} // sort all items in collections event by custom metafield similar to the standard date field

{% for event in allevents %} // loop through all events
 {% assign eventdate = event['Start time and date'] | date: "%d" %} // assign event date from the custom meta in the event item
 {% if eventdate == today %} // check if event date equals today
     {% if event.url == page.url %} // check if event url is also currently generated page url

       {% assign preveventindex = forloop.index | plus: 1 %} // find the index of previous event in the array
       {% assign nexteventindex = forloop.index | minus: 1 %} // find the index of next event in the array

       {% for event in allevents %} // loop throug events again 
         {% assign today = site.time | date: "%d" %} // set current date again
         {% assign eventdate = event['Start time and date'] | date: "%d" %} // set event date again

         {% if eventdate == today %} // check if event generated has current date 
           {% if forloop.index == nexteventindex %} // check if next event index is correct

             {{ forloop.index }} -
             {{ event.url }}
             {% assign nexteventurl = event.url %} // get the url is next item in the array has the same date as current item 

             // You can now use the url to navigate to the next item in the array that must have todays date

        {% endif %}

        {% if forloop.index == preveventindex %}
          {{ forloop.index }} -
          {{ event.url }}
          {% assign preveventurl = event.url %}

          // You can now use the url to navigate to the previous item in the array that must have todays date

        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```